# In Python, how do I make my code run in a custom sized window?

Tags: python, resize, window, window-resize

I need to know the CODE to change the size of the window that comes up when I run my python file. I am making a chess game using text, and the size of the board is too tall to fit in the little window that comes up when I run my code. I don't want to have to do it manually, I need to make it a specific size so that I know what spacing to use so that when it prints the chess board to the window, it will be fully visible without any of the previous board visible. Is there a way to do that? Right now the default size is like 25 lines in length, 50-80 lines would be optimal. Thanks to whoever knows how to do this, or if it is even possible!

I don't know if this is important, but I am using Python 2.7 and I am running Windows 7.

I believe I am using it in IDLE... I don't have anything else installed to execute .py files besides whatever came with the installation of Python 2.7.6.

Comment: What GUI are you using? Tkinter?

Comment: Are you using the command prompt? The IDLE interpreter?

Comment: How are you running the code? IDLE? cmd? IDLE defaults to 24x80 characters.

Comment: its possible, but only on windows, and it will be gross. Look up `SetConsoleWindowInfo` on MSDN, and python's ctypes module